# numpy datetime64 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a `pandas DataFrame` consisting of 3 columns, with the first column an hourly timeseries of dtype `np.datetime64`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
timeseries = np.arange(np.datetime64('20/11/2009'), np.datetime64('19/11/2010), np.timedelta64(1, 'h'))
insolation =pd.DataFrame(columns=['datetime','GHI','DNI'])
insolation['datetime'] = timeseries
```

If I `print(insolation)` I get this output:

```
                   datetime  GHI  DNI
0    2009-11-20 00:00:00  NaN  NaN
1    2009-11-20 01:00:00  NaN  NaN
2    2009-11-20 02:00:00  NaN  NaN
...                  ...  ...  ...
8734 2010-11-18 22:00:00  NaN  NaN
8735 2010-11-18 23:00:00  NaN  NaN
```

So far, so good. But if I use this datetime64 object:

```
datetime=np.datetime64('2009-11-20 00:00:00')
```

(which does seem to exist in the DataFrame) to reference the DataFrame:

```
insolation[datetime][GHI] =1.0
```

I get an error:

```
KeyError: numpy.datetime64('2009-11-20T00:00:00')
```

Full error message is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1945, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: numpy.datetime64('2009-11-20T00:00:00')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PYTHONprojects/PY_EN_Models/Scripts/create_weatherfile.py", line 109, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/PYTHONprojects/PY_EN_Models/Scripts/create_weatherfile.py", line 87, in main
    insolation[datetime][GHI] = irradience_array[gridrow,gridcol]
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1350, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3290, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\z5044992\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: numpy.datetime64('2009-11-20T00:00:00')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `loc`

```
insolation.loc[insolation.datetime.eq(datetime), 'GHI'] = 1.0
```

---

what went wrong?

```
insolation[datetime]
```

Tries to get the column defined by the variable `datetime`.
***Tip:*** don't use variable names that are the same as your column names.